# Obtener el nombre del dato que mas se repite en un groupby en python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Necesito saber como sacar el nombre del dato que más se repite, tengo lo siguiente:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ciaocamilo/misiontic2022/main/encuesta_chololates.csv', sep=';')

precios = df.groupby(['PRECIO']).size()

print(precios)
```

estoy obteniendo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven el valor que más se repite es 8000 con 56 veces, el numero de veces que se repite el numero lo estoy sacando con:

```
cant = max(precios)
```

pero lo que necesito es que me diga que el numero 8000 es el que mas se repite, nose como hacerlo, intente con esto:

```
precio_max = precios.keys()
```

pero me sale esto:

Precio seleccionado': Int64Index([8000, 10000, 12000, 15000], dtype='int64', name='PRECIO')

he intentado de varias maneras pero la más cercana es esta, si pueden ayudarme se los agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, sería recomendable aplicarle índices al groupby con reset_index() a fin que los índices te puedan ayudar:

```
data = precios.reset_index()
```

Luego, obtienes el valor del índice donde está el valor que encontraste:

```
indice= data.loc[data[0]==cant].index
print(indice)
```

Finalmente puedes tener esto:

```
valor = data["PRECIO"][indice][0]
print('El valor es ', valor)
```

Comment: Uff si me sirvió, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Sería bueno valores la respuesta y la marques como aceptada, para que otros que tengan el mismo problema al consultar esta pregunta puedan ver cual fue la solución.

Comment: Soy nueva en esto, ya la marque como aceptada, pero nose como valorarla, me podrías indicar por favor, gracias!

Comment: con dar con la flecha arriba del cero.

Comment: Aaah vale listo, ya lo hice, muchas gracias!